# Xamarin iTunes Affliate Links

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xamarin.ios, xamarin

My apps open iTunes Affliate links directly using the standard sharedApplication.OpenURL. However, Apple recommends the following code.

Is there a C# version to support Xamarin?

```
// Process a LinkShare/TradeDoubler/DGM URL to something iPhone can handle
(void)openReferralURL:(NSURL *)referralURL
{
  NSURLRequest *theRequest=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:referralURL cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:30.0];
  NSURLConnection *conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];
  [conn release];
}

// Save the most recent URL in case multiple redirects occur
// "iTunesURL" is an NSURL property in your class declaration               
(NSURLRequest *)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection willSendRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request redirectResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{

if (response) {
    NSMutableURLRequest *r = [[request mutableCopy] autorelease]; // original request
    [r setURL: [request URL]];

    self.iTunesURL = [r URL];                    
    if ([self.iTunesURL.host hasSuffix:@"itunes.apple.com"]) {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:self.iTunesURL];
    }
    return r;
 } else {
    return request;
 }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Couldn't find an existing API, so I wrote it:

Enjoy!

```
    NSUrlRequest theRequest;
    NSUrlConnection conn;

    void Process (NSUrl url)
    {
        theRequest = new NSUrlRequest (url, NSUrlRequestCachePolicy.UseProtocolCachePolicy, 30);
        var del = new LinkDelegate ();
        conn = new NSUrlConnection (theRequest, del);
        conn.Start ();
    }
}

class LinkDelegate: NSUrlConnectionDelegate
{

    public override NSUrlRequest WillSendRequest (NSUrlConnection connection, NSUrlRequest request, NSUrlResponse response)
    {
        if (response!=null) {
            var url = request.Url;
            if (url.Host.ToLower ().Contains ("itunes.apple.com"))
                UIApplication.SharedApplication.OpenUrl (url);
            return NSUrlRequest.FromUrl (url);
        } else {
            return request; 
        }
    }
}
```